How to use copyrighted music or sfx in a youtube video without resorting to fair use
I'm a new youtuber and I would like to learn how to use copyrighted content (specifically audio clips) in my video. I don't know how to approach getting legit permission to use copyrighted content in my video and I don't want to resort to fair use risking the longevity of my video and or even channel expecially since I just started. At the moment I have been relying on music with the creative commons licence primarily from Kevin MacLeod. But when I worked on a skit themed around skyrim I want to use a clip from the song "Dragonborn" or "The One They Fear" and the "Unrelenting Force" shout sfx but I don't know who to get permission from (Microsoft, Bethesda, Jeremy Soule), how to get permission to use the content from either these three entities or people and how to get the audio after getting permission to use it.

YouTube has its own rules and standards. If you want to make money from ads in your YouTube videos, you probably can’t use any copyrighted content. The least bad thing YouTube will do if you use copyrighted content is “de-monetize” your video, which means you won’t get any money for ads run in your video. I’m not sure what you mean by “resorting” to fair use, but that phrase makes me think you might not understand fair use (98% of people don’t).

The easiest way to do this is to use rights approved music from a production music library service (eg AudioNetwork). You need to pay for the music to do this, but the prices are usually fairly low.
If you want to use commercial music from a record company, you need to go through their licensing approval, which can be more time consuming and expensive depending on the track, and depending on the purpose you're using it for. You can usually work out who the correct record company to contact is by looking up the details on eg Spotify or Discogs. So for this example, you'd need to contact Bethesda:
https://www.discogs.com/label/705294-Bethesda

I tried getting permission from Bethesda a bit ago but they responded that using any assets from their game is not allowed. I then asked about gameplay footage I recorded but they never responded. I had to resort to making my own parody sound effect for the shout but couldn't include music.

Bethesda finally responded with something completely contrary to the I can't use their assets for a youtube video. Saying that they encorage creators now I'm confused
